# Can I make the razor syntax simpler

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following:

```
@if ((@Model.SeqId != 0) & (Model.SeqId != 1))
  {
  <text>
  window.location.href = "www.stackoverflow.com";
  </text>
}
```

I don't know much about razor. Is there something I could do to make it simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Suffice to define a property on your view model

```
public bool ShouldRedirectToSO 
{
    get
    {
        return (SeqId != 0 && SeqId != 1);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@if (Model.ShouldRedirectToSO)
{
    @:window.location.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';
}
</script>
```

or if you intend to redirect immediately on page load if the condition is met you could also do this directly from the controller:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = ...
    if (model.ShouldRedirectToSO)
    {
        return Redirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com");    
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can SeqId ever be less than 0?  If not, you could do

```
@if (Model.SeqId > 1)
{
  <text>
  window.location.href = "www.stackoverflow.com";
  </text>
}
```

Also, you don't need to @ the Model in a code block.  You probably want to use && instead of & as this fails as soon as the first test is false, saves a few CPU cycles.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.71).aspx